# whole project rolled back, new project gone on Git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository, git-commit

Since my git somehow had some contradiction not making it work, I decided to delete my git because it was old. I create a new remote, and I make a cohering branch. Now trying to switch branch, I get an error saying I need commit changes (I am looking at my newest code of the project).

I press commit (having already deleted this local git), and it switches over to my newly create remote branch. But for some reasons my project now look alike what it did half a year ago, and I can't find the new files?

EDIT: I am almost certain this was a bug enforced by the fact that Xcode and terminal commands was perceiving what was the current branch differently(no idea why). I was then forced by Xcode to commit changes to a branch that didn't exist. Somehow this made my project turn into an old version of the project, losing all files that had been added later etc.

Comment: You need to give us more details I believe.

Comment: What can I add pls? The info I have is very vague since it happened unexpected. Can you enlighten me, if you have a local git and delete this, will that delete the project too?

Comment: It sounds like you branched off a really old branch.  Can you try cloning a new repository?

Comment: Basically I was deleting all locales but the current (becuz terminal don't allow that without doing sth extra). Xcode was showing current branch being other than terminal was showing (i don't know why). Anyway, before i was allowed to switch to my newly created branch(and remote) i had to commit chagnes to current branch (which i had deleted from term). After doing that it changed to the newly created remote branch( i didn't create off another branch afaik), and project gone. I will look into cloning a new rep, Im not sure what u mean

Comment: You need to go back to the last place where you were not lost.  Create a new repo from scratch and use the most recent version of the branch pushed to the repository.  This is a safe approach I believe.

Comment: i think the problem happened, because Xcode and terminal didn't refer to the same branch being "current." Hence I deleted the Xcode current branch from terminal. When i wanted to switch branch inside Xcode (which still had the branch listed even after reloading and cleaning), it required me to commit before being able to change. I think committing to a place that didn't exist made it delete all the newest code(code i was looking at) and chose to make my project something old. I rly cannot grasp how pressing commit would ever wipe new files/code from my local. I didn't have a remote at the time

Answer (score 0):

In this case, due to deleting current branch, I was able to retrieve the  ID easily because it was still showing in console after deleting the branch. Reverting a branch deletion is then simple:

```
git branch branchName <SHA>
```

I could then switch to that brand and my project came back.

I have decided to delete .git-folder and make a new repo to avoid further complications with contradictions.